# In java, is a runnable transaction safe?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, thread-safety, runnable

I came across some code looking like this:

```
someMethod(){
    ..............
    transactionalUtils.newTransaction(()-> {someStuffHere})
}
```

Where `transactionalUtils.newTransaction` looks like this

```
public void newTransaction(Runnable job) {
        job.run();
    }
```

Im perplexed by the simplicity of it. Is this really transaction safe? A separate Runnable always initiates and closes its own transaction?
Explanation and further references would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll have to define what a "transaction" is in this context.

Comment: Presumably that method is there to be overridden.  An instance of `transactionalUtils` running against a database, for example, may hold a conncection's transaction open for the duration of the `run` followed by a commit or rollback.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know what type, and what framework or library, `transactionUtils` is from.

Comment: If the code is really what you posted, then it's strictly equivalnt to `someStuffHere`, and this transactionUtils.newTransaction() is just useless noise.

Comment: @JBNizet, Maybe it's a placeholder for something that the author forgot to go back and finish.